# Why boost async_connect doesn't call my callback?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to implement a kind of syslog protocol client in boost asio. I succeeded with UDP async version and I am trying to develop TCP version, but stuck. I used WinSyslog and Debian rsyslog as server and Wireshark to control data flow.

I wrote TcpConnection class and prepared test data for it. I use boost asio tcp socket and I expect that packet would be sent using connect and send handlers, but connect handler didn't called.

My Implementation:

```cpp
class TcpConnection
, public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnection>
{
public:
    TcpConnection(
        boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
        uint32_t to,
    uint16_t port)    
    : m_socket(io_service)
    , m_ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4(to), port)
    {
        m_socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
    }

    void SendMessageAsync(const boost::asio::const_buffer& message) override
    {
    /*
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        m_socket.connect(m_ep, ec);
        m_socket.send(message, 0, ec);*/
  
        m_socket.async_connect(m_ep, 
            boost::bind(&TcpConnection::HandleConnect, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, message));
    }
 
private:

    void HandleConnect(boost::system::error_code const& ec, const boost::asio::const_buffer& message)
    {
        if (!ec) {
            ec.message();
        }
        else
        {
            m_socket.async_send(message,
                boost::bind(&TcpConnection::HandleWritten, shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
    }
    void HandleWritten(boost::system::error_code const& ec, size_t bytes_transferred)
    {   
        if (!ec) {
            EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << TR << ec.message();
    }
}

private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
    const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint m_ep;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    auto connection = boost::make_shared<protocoller::syslog::TcpConnection>(
         io_service, asio::ip::address::from_string("10.16.82.22"), 514);

    auto messageStr = "syslog report"
    connection->SendMessageAsync(boost::asio::buffer(boost::asio::buffer(messageStr.data(), messageStr.size())));
    Sleep(5000);
}
```

I placed breakpoint in HandleConnect and this method never called. I used wireshark and there is successfull connection, but my handler didn't invoked:

[image: wireshark]

I tried to find problem with BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING, but there was only `@asio|1695732320.140556|0*1|socket@01580998.async_connect`

And finally I tried to send by blocking socket and everything work good, so I have a problem only with async sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to `run()` the `io_context` in your code.

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    auto connection = boost::make_shared<protocoller::syslog::TcpConnection>(
         io_service, asio::ip::address::from_string("10.16.82.22"), 514);

    auto messageStr = "syslog report"
    connection->SendMessageAsync(boost::asio::buffer(boost::asio::buffer(messageStr.data(), messageStr.size())));

    m_io_service.run_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
}
```

Here's some fixed-up version that works (some conditions were also wrong and the code wasn't self-contained):

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3f97930b6d60fb1)**

[image]

Note that there are considerable issues with the interfaces and soon with thread-safety, unless you intend to only send one message per connection (which is does look like...?) but then the whole class should be a function.

Also consider using executors instead of service references.

Comment: Added some measure of code-review to enable a live demo

Comment: Thank you! Yes, my problem is in io_service::run(). Can you answer why async UDP send is working without io-service::run? And I tried to do something like     m_thread.Create(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service)); to run io_service in connection class or in Client class - but this doesn't help. I rechecked it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: That would be implementation defined: the [initiation of the async operation](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/async_ops.html) apparently may cause the kernel or hardware to complete the operation - though the completion handler will never fire then. The thread approach should work unless it runs out of work before you ever post async work. I highly recommend doing as I suggested: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8938a964e454bc6a

Comment: Can you do a favor, and giva some advise. I'm trying to upgrade this TcpConnection and use SSL encryption. And I stuck with async_connect and async_handshake - do I need both? And your solution is async, but I can't find something that prevent SendMessageAsync to closed socket.  Or I'm not right? I mean in my test all calls to SendMessageAsync finished before handshake established

Comment: Why don't you show your code? Did you already fix your interface perhaps more like in my last comment? Here's the favor https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fb659c295ef5ec8 - with a a local demo. I didn't know how to get rsyslog to accept TLS connections so I used `s_server`: https://i.imgur.com/AgJfHUU.mp4

Comment: Forgot to remove the unused packaged_task: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/753bfd4fc5fb9d14