# How to use boost resolver with async connect?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to add resolver to my async UDP socket connection class. I use connect/send interface and I want to resolve and connect in connect, and send data in send. I expect that resolve async in callback give me a range of endpoints and I should iterate over it to find available endpoint. So I implemented connect method, that checks all endpoints, but it looks monstrous and unjustifiably complex.

```
void UdpConnection::Connect()
{
    std::promise<void> connectPromise;
    auto connectFuture = connectPromise.get_future();

    auto handleResolveCallback = [this, p = std::move(connectPromise), self = shared_from_this()]
        (const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator) mutable 
            {
                if (ec)
                {
                    p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
                }
                else
                {
                    while (endpoint_iterator != boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver::iterator())
                    {
                        try {
                            std::promise<void> connectPromise2;
                            auto connectFuture2 = connectPromise2.get_future();

                            boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint iter = *endpoint_iterator;
                            boost::asio::post(m_socket.get_executor(),
                                [this, p = std::move(connectPromise2), self = shared_from_this(), iter]() mutable { DoConnect(std::move(p), std::move(iter)); });

                            connectFuture2.get();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (const std::exception& ex)
                        {
                            std::cout<< "Run-time exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
                            ++endpoint_iterator;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
    
    m_resolver.async_resolve(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), m_to.c_str(), m_port.c_str(), std::move(handleResolveCallback));
    connectFuture.get();
}
void UdpConnection::DoConnect(std::promise<void> p, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint iter)
{
    auto handleConnect = [p = std::move(p), self = shared_from_this()](const boost::system::error_code& ec) mutable
    {
        EKA_TRACE_DEBUG_EX(self->GetTracer()) << TR << "Connect: " << ec.message();

        if (ec)
            p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
        else {
            p.set_value();
        }
    };

    m_socket.async_connect(iter, std::move(handleConnect));
}
```

And I don't know why it doesn't call DoConnect, it stucks in connectFuture.get(). In traces:

```
@asio|1696946039.156806|0*1|thread_pool@01059240.execute(blk=never,rel=fork)
@asio|1696946039.156806|>1|
@asio|1696946039.157804|>0|
@asio|1696946039.874930|0*2|thread_pool@01059240.execute(blk=never,rel=fork)
```

What is the correct method to resolve and async connect?

Full example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/737a0927ecd74458

P.S. I know that UDP con't use connection, however TCP and UDP have similar interface in boost, so I think my problem is not in protocol.

Comment: @sehe, master, I need some jedi power

Comment: [This is a new thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77260094/how-to-copy-vertex-properties-of-boost-graph-which-contains-a-graph-itself/77262004#comment136208227_77260094) for me. I prefer to choose my own priorities/schedule :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting the work, then immediately blocking on it - this is by definition useless. You could always just call the function you posted directly instead.

And this highlights the problem: you block *on the service thread*, thus ensuring that no handlers can run. Which means, the `DoConnect` task will never run.

Instead, organize the async call chain such that nothing ever blocks inside a (completion) handler. E.g. how I did it [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77180239/why-boost-async-connect-doesnt-call-my-callback#comment136131773_77180943) with the related TCP question:

**[Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/753bfd4fc5fb9d14)**

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;

namespace protocoller::syslog {
    static inline std::ostream& EKA_TRACE_ERROR() {
        thread_local std::ostream instance(std::cout.rdbuf());
        return instance;
    }

    struct IConnection {
        virtual ~IConnection()                          = default;
        virtual void Connect()                          = 0;
        virtual void SendMessageAsync(std::string_view) = 0;
        virtual void Close()                            = 0;
    };

    struct TcpConnection
        : IConnection
        , std::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnection> //
    {
        TcpConnection(asio::any_io_executor ex, tcp::endpoint ep, ssl::context& ctx)
            : m_socket(make_strand(ex), ctx)
            , m_ep(ep) {}

        void Connect() override {
            std::promise<void> p;
            auto f = p.get_future();
            asio::post(m_socket.get_executor(),
                       [this, p = std::move(p), self = shared_from_this()]() mutable { //
                           do_connect(std::move(p));
                       });
            f.get();
        }

        void Close() override {
            asio::post(m_socket.get_executor(), [this, self = shared_from_this()] { do_close(); });
        }

        void SendMessageAsync(std::string_view message) override {
            asio::post(m_socket.get_executor(),
                       [this, self = shared_from_this(), msg = std::string(message)]() mutable {
                           outbox_.push_back(std::move(msg));
                           if (outbox_.size() == 1)
                               do_send_loop();
                       });
        }

      private:
        void do_connect(std::promise<void> p) {
            EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "Connecting to: " << m_ep << std::endl;
            m_socket.next_layer().async_connect(
                m_ep, [this, p = std::move(p), self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec) mutable {
                    EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "Connect: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    if (ec)
                        p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
                    else {
                        m_socket.async_handshake( //
                            Stream::client, [p = std::move(p), self](error_code ec) mutable {
                                EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "Handshake: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                if (ec)
                                    p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
                                else
                                    p.set_value();
                            });
                    }
                });
        }

        void do_send_loop() {
            if (outbox_.empty())
                return;
            EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "SendLoop: " << quoted(outbox_.front()) << std::endl;
            outbox_.front() += "\n";
            asio::async_write( //
                m_socket, asio::buffer(outbox_.front()),
                [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
                    EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "HandleWritten: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    if (!ec) {
                        outbox_.pop_front();
                        do_send_loop();
                    }
                });
        }

        void do_close() {
            EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "Closing connection" << std::endl;
            m_socket.async_shutdown([self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec) {
                EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "Shutdown: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            });
        }

      private:
        using Stream = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;
        std::deque<std::string> outbox_;
        Stream                  m_socket;
        tcp::endpoint           m_ep;
    };
} // namespace protocoller::syslog

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    asio::thread_pool ioc{1};
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tls_client};
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    using namespace protocoller::syslog;
    std::shared_ptr<IConnection> conn =
        std::make_shared<TcpConnection>(ioc.get_executor(), tcp::endpoint{{}, 12514}, ctx);

    conn->Connect();

    std::vector<std::string> words(argv+1, argv+argc);
    words.push_back("bye world");
    for (auto w : words)
        conn->SendMessageAsync("syslog tls client: " + w);


    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5000ms);
    conn->Close();

    ioc.join();
}
```

### Update: Review

Reading your [full example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/737a0927ecd74458) there are... many problems.

- your abstract base class lacks a virtual dtor
- you are using different strands for things that *should* be on the same strand, fix:

  ```
       , m_socket(make_strand(ex), udp::v4())
       , m_resolver(m_socket.get_executor()) {}
  ```
- you are mixing `boost::enable_shared_from_this` with `std::shared_ptr`
- In your `Connect` you immediately invoke `async_resolve`, the idea is to post **that** to the strand
- The completion handler(s) will actually **be** on the strand, so the `asio::post` you /had/ was useless there
- `asio::post` is an async initiation, meaning it will **always** immediately return (and without exception), making the loop useless too.
- Instead of manually enumerating endpoints, use `asio::async_connect`
- You have a second promise. You only promise 1 thing. The second promise only causes you to want to block on the first. That was your entire issue. Don't. Just pass the original promise along until the connection actually completed

  > P.S. Ironically, I later noticed that clearly you based your example on the above TCP TLS client (as evidenced by the "wrong" `"syslog tls client: "` string). As you will see in the summary below, it had *exactly* the solution that you needed before you removed it :)
- You had changed the `msg = std::string(msg)` from the `SendMessageAsync` lambda. That creates [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the string view may refer to memory no longer available when the async operation runs. This is also why it is *extremely* important that `m_outbox` contain `std::string`, not `std::string_view`.
- You `async_send_to` to `m_ep` but `m_ep` is never assigned. Therefore, nothing will ever be sent (let alone arrive)
- Since you're trying to test the resolver, you should probably change the constructor arguments from:

  ```
   std::shared_ptr<IConnection> conn =
       std::make_shared<UdpConnection>(ioc.get_executor(), "127.0.0.1", "514");
  ```

  To something more like:

  ```
   std::shared_ptr<IConnection> conn =
       std::make_shared<UdpConnection>(ioc.get_executor(), "localhost", "syslog");
  ```

Fixing all these things you get:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f65ff55e8c9d8b7)**

```
// #define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

struct IConnection {
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
    using udp        = asio::ip::udp;

    virtual ~IConnection()                          = default;
    virtual void Connect()                          = 0;
    virtual void SendMessageAsync(std::string_view) = 0;
    virtual void Close()                            = 0;
};

class UdpConnection
    : public IConnection
    , public std::enable_shared_from_this<UdpConnection> {
  public:
    UdpConnection(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::string to, std::string port);

    void Connect()                                  override; 
    void SendMessageAsync(std::string_view message) override; 
    void Close()                                    override; 

  private:
    void DoSendLoop();
    void HandleWritten(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred);
    void DoConnect(std::promise<void> p);

  private:
    const std::string m_to;
    const std::string m_port;

    udp::socket   m_socket;
    udp::resolver m_resolver;
    udp::endpoint m_ep;

    std::deque<std::string> m_outbox;
};

UdpConnection::UdpConnection(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::string to, std::string port)
    : m_to(std::move(to))
    , m_port(std::move(port))
    , m_socket(make_strand(ex), udp::v4())
    , m_resolver(m_socket.get_executor()) {}

void UdpConnection::Connect() {
    std::promise<void> p;
    auto f = p.get_future();

    asio::post(                                                          //
        m_socket.get_executor(),                                         //
        [this, p = std ::move(p), self = shared_from_this()]() mutable { //
            DoConnect(std::move(p));
        });
    f.get();
}

void UdpConnection::SendMessageAsync(std::string_view message) {
    asio::post(m_socket.get_executor(),
               [this, self = shared_from_this(), msg = std::string(message)]() mutable {
                   m_outbox.emplace_back(std::move(msg));
                   if (m_outbox.size() == 1)
                       DoSendLoop();
               });
}

void UdpConnection::DoSendLoop()
{
    if (m_outbox.empty())
        return;

    m_socket.async_send_to( //
        asio::buffer(m_outbox.front()), m_ep,
        bind(&UdpConnection::HandleWritten, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1,
             std::placeholders::_2));
}

void UdpConnection::Close()
{
    try {
        if (m_socket.is_open()) {
            error_code ignoredEc;
            m_socket.shutdown(udp::socket::shutdown_both, ignoredEc);
            m_socket.close(ignoredEc);
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& ex) {
        std::cout<< "Run-time exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void UdpConnection::HandleWritten(error_code  ec, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
    m_outbox.pop_front();

    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Connect: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }

    DoSendLoop();
}

void UdpConnection::DoConnect(std::promise<void> p) {
    m_resolver.async_resolve(
        udp::v4(), m_to, m_port,
        [this, p = std::move(p), self = shared_from_this()] //
        (error_code ec, udp::resolver::iterator eps) mutable {
            if (ec) {
                p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
            } else {
                asio::async_connect( //
                    m_socket, eps,
                    [this, p = std::move(p), self = shared_from_this()] //
                    (error_code ec, udp::resolver::iterator it) mutable {
                        if (ec) {
                            std::cout << "Connect: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
                        } else {
                            m_ep = it->endpoint();
                            std::cout << "Connect: " << m_ep << std::endl;
                            p.set_value();
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    asio::thread_pool ioc{1};

    std::shared_ptr<IConnection> conn =
        std::make_shared<UdpConnection>(ioc.get_executor(), "localhost", "syslog");

    conn->Connect();

    std::vector<std::string> words(argv + 1, argv + argc);
    words.push_back("bye world");
    for (auto w : words)
        conn->SendMessageAsync("syslog udp client: " + w);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5000ms);
    conn->Close();

    ioc.join();
}
```

With a local demonstration:

[image]

### Summary

In short, the promise is *only* there for the end user to synchronize on connection completion. You never block inside handlers.

Also, interestingly enough, all this was already demonstrated in the [TLS-enabled example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77180239/why-boost-async-connect-doesnt-call-my-callback#comment136131805_77180943) that you apparently took as the starting point:

```
void do_connect(std::promise<void> p) {
    EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "Connecting to: " << m_ep << std::endl;
    m_socket.next_layer().async_connect(
        m_ep, [this, p = std::move(p), self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec) mutable {
            EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "Connect: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            if (ec)
                p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
            else {
                m_socket.async_handshake( //
                    Stream::client, [p = std::move(p), self](error_code ec) mutable {
                        EKA_TRACE_ERROR() << "Handshake: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                        if (ec)
                            p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
                        else
                            p.set_value();
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

This is structurally identical to the `DoConnect` that we ended up with after all the fixes:

```
void UdpConnection::DoConnect(std::promise<void> p) {
    m_resolver.async_resolve(
        udp::v4(), m_to, m_port,
        [this, p = std::move(p), self = shared_from_this()] //
        (error_code ec, udp::resolver::iterator eps) mutable {
            if (ec) {
                p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
            } else {
                asio::async_connect( //
                    m_socket, eps,
                    [this, p = std::move(p), self = shared_from_this()] //
                    (error_code ec, udp::resolver::iterator it) mutable {
                        if (ec) {
                            std::cout << "Connect: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            p.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
                        } else {
                            m_ep = it->endpoint();
                            std::cout << "Connect: " << m_ep << std::endl;
                            p.set_value();
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

---

Comment: I can show how to integrate the async resolve, which incidentally also will remove some problems (you call `endpoint iter` which suggests the problem). However it will have to wait a bit until I have time

Comment: Updated with full review, problem breakdown (there were a few) and fixed version.

Comment: Thank you! Some mistakes are connected with sample, but there are few questions. About bosst::enable_shared_from_this and shared_ptr it is prototype mistake too. I concentrated on DoConnect. My main mistake was in attempts to iterate over endpoints by myself. And yoy correct, basically I tried to use async_handshare as example.

Comment: @drem1lin Even with manual loop, it would still look almost the same, here with injected ipv6 endpoint to demonstrate the loop happening (see commented): https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/626f5f4d723a06b0 local demo https://i.imgur.com/4tYeGYK.mp4

Comment: Yep, I tried to do somethink like that;) And I create those moster. Thank you